# Approach to solve cubic inequality

Tags: cubics

I would be happy to get some ideas on possible approaches to solve
$$
x^3 - x^2 < 2x - 2\qquad (x \in \mathbb R).
$$

Comment: Factorise it: $x^2(x-1)<2(x-1)$ i.e. $(x^2-2)(x-1)<0$ i.e. $(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})(x-1)<0$. When is the product of three numbers negative?

Comment: Factorise $x^3-x^2-2x+2$ and use wavy curve method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^3-x^2-2x-2<0$$

$$(x-1)(x^2-2)<0$$

$$x\in (-\infty, -\sqrt2)\cup(1,\sqrt2)$$

[image]

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Thank you! What software did you use for the graph?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-x%5E2%3C2x-2